# Exclude widget's input fields from being submitted in parent form

Tags: jquery, form-submit, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I've created a widget using the [widget factory](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/) and have added elements like `<input>` that are required by it. This widget can be initialized inside a `form` element, resulting in submitting the added fields when the parent form is submitted.

I want to tell `form` not to submit the specified inputs, and this must be done inside the widget since this is the one knowing the added `input` elements.

The idea is to get the closest `form` from inside widget and disable the inputs (eg `.prop("disabled", true)`) just before submitting the form, and re-enable them afterwards.

It is important **not to** bother code outside the widget, I want to keep coupling low.

Unfortunatelly, during `_create` of the widget, the `this.element` isn't added to the `DOM` so there is no way to add a handler to the form's submit event.

Sample code:

```
$(function ()
{
    $.widget("Foo.Widget",{
        _create: function(){
            this.element.append($("<input type='radio'>").attr("name", "theInput"));

            // bind to the containing form's submit event
            var form = this.elemeng.closest("form"); // returns $()

        };

    });
});
```

It is possible to bind latter, but this would require the user to interact with the widget somehow, which isn't mandatory.

I could add a timer and bind it a little latter, since the user won't submit it during the first couple of second (evil solution).

Also, I could pass either the context of the widget or the parent `form` as options but this is something I want to avoid.

Comment: My advice is create a dummy form, add elements to it and then submit it.

Comment: You can add a class="nosubmit" to the form elements that should not be submitted in the form, then you $('input').each(function(){ var elem = $(this); if (!elem.hasClass('notsubmit') copy_to_dummy_form(elem); });

Comment: You could beside input also be interested in $('select') and $('textarea')